# vlookup multiple returns excel

Tags: excel, vlookup

I am working with a data set of students information at a local university.

I used a VLOOKUP, using the IDs of the students as the unique identifier. But my problem is that the VLOOKUP only requires one row of information and half of the students in the study have more than 5 lines each. How can I make EXCEL return multiple lines?

Comment: Please post a sample of your data. I'm not sure I understand your question.

Comment: Even if Excel returns the valuies from 5 cells, your formular itself is in a single cell. What do you want to appear in that cell?

Comment: I have a list of engineering students and I want to pull out the lines that belong to those students in engineering. However, the normal vlookup is only returning one of the lines for each student instead of the multiple ones that have the same ID.

Comment: See this [link](http://www.get-digital-help.com/2009/10/25/how-to-return-multiple-values-using-vlookup-in-excel/)

Answer (score 2):

VLookup will return the first row matching or closely matching the condition depending on the last boolean function parameter. It is assumed that the ID is unique and not repeated several times in the table you are searching in.

As far as I understand the issue, either you find a way to make a unique key for the lookup table so a key loking like 'ID + another column' formatted in a unique way such as 'ID - Other ID' or you will have to use VBA to retrieve all the rows matching a certain non unique condition.

If the job at hand is small, or VBA cannot be considered, and it is acceptable to work it out manually using auto Filters to do the matching/retrieving could help.

Comment: What is vba? Also the sample size is huge.

Comment: VBA stands for Visual Basic For Application and allows you to write code to help with the Spreadsheet various functionalities. It is a widely used and well known software language. If in Excel you press the keys ALT+F11 you will see the VBA Editor.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your issue:
have you tried playing with VLOOKUP([range_lookup] = TRUE/FALSE) ?

If not, I'd guess your best bet would be to Create a unique, combined ID for each student. Try posting a reproducible example :)

Comment: I have a list of engineering students and I want to pull out the lines that belong to those students in engineering. However, the normal vlookup is only returning one of the lines for each student instead of the multiple ones that have the same ID.

Comment: VLOOKUP will always return one unique row observation of your data. You can create a unique ID, like "ID_Course_Campus" in a separate column, and then VLOOKUP those.
Another option would be to use a Pivot Table with a filter.

Answer (score 0):

You need to short duplicate entries into two separate column, and look in to both column.

I did that if you have logical though, you can do it.