# Use of Sheet 1 one column value of excel in Sheet 2

Tags: vba, excel

I have two 2 sheets in one excel (sheet1 and sheet2)
In sheet 1 the following details are there, There are two columns which are following.
Student Class   Student Name
And in sheet 2 I have only one column in which there is some text .
Eg :- 
This Project Statement is subject to the Master Agreement effective as of the date written above between  ***Student Class*** and Student name.

Question :- I need to put Student Class from sheet 1 in the bold part of column 1 sheet 2 .
Please help me.

Comment: Is the text in Sheet 2 the same for each Student Class and Student Name?

Comment: No , It should be different . Like if you are giving class 9 sheet 1 than it should be showing class 9 in sheet 2

Comment: I recommend you look into `VLOOKUP`. This vlookup question has been asked many times - see http://stackoverflow.com/a/5382405/4606130 which has a nice example to work through and explain MATCH and INDEX as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [vlookup multiple returns excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17702734/vlookup-multiple-returns-excel)

Comment: Sorry , but this did not help . I need the data of cell 1 from sheet 1 to cell 1 of sheet 2 but it should replace the data of bold part of cell 1 sheet 2.

Answer (score 1):

If i'm understanding you correctly, you could use CONCATENATE. For example:

`=CONCATENATE(Sheet1!A1, "Text" Or Cell reference from sheet 2, Sheet1!B1)`

and if you need to separate the values add in " " or "-" or something like this:

`=CONCATENATE(Sheet1!A1," ","Text" Or Cell reference from sheet 2," ",Sheet1!B1)`